# Problem with ForeignKeys in sqlalchemy Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, firebird

When I then send the query, neither the BSM_ID nor the employee field are displayed.

I have the following models:

```py
class Bprojpod(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'BPROJPOD'
  ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  ZEIT_VON = db.Column(db.String)
  ZEIT_BIS = db.Column(db.String)
  PAUSE = db.Column(db.String)
  BSM_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey("BSM.ID"))
  EMPLOYEE = relationship("Bsm", foreign_keys=[BSM_ID])
  BTICK_ID = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Bsm(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = "BSM"
  ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  NAME = db.Column(db.String)

class BprojpodSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
  class Meta:
    model = Bprojpod
    load_instance = True
    sqla_session = db.session

bprojpod_schema = BprojpodSchema()
abprojpod_schema = BprojpodSchema(many=True)
```

This is how I call the query:

```py
def getBprojpod(btick_id):
      abprojpod = Bprojpod.query.filter(Bprojpod.BTICK_ID == btick_id).all()
      return abprojpod_schema.dump(abprojpod)
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is it that a specific field isn't being displayed by your dump function? There's not really a reproducible bug here.

Comment: Yes the fields Emplyee and BSM_ID from the Bprojpod Model are not displayed by print function.

Comment: `.dump` isn't part of SQLAlchemy, at least that I'm aware of. Perhaps it's part of some other library you're using. Maybe you could post its source code too, or update your question to let us know what library you're using for it?

You might try just printing out the attributes to make sure they're there though.